# Why is my answer to this probability question wrong?

Tags: probability

The question is as follows:

> Two marbles are drawn in succession from a box containing 10 red, 30 white, 20 blue and 15 orange marbles, with replacement being made after each drawing.
>
> Find the probability that:
> (a) Both marbles are white.
> (b) The first marble is red and the second marble is white.
> (c) Neither marble is orange. Solve this problem assuming that no replacement is made after each drawing.

My issue lies with part (c).

My approach for part (c) (assuming the marbles are replaced) is as follows:

> $P(\text {first marble is orange}) = \frac{15} {75}$
>
> $P(\text {second marble is orange}) = \frac{15} {75}$
>
> $P(\text {both marbles are orange}) = \frac{15} {75} * \frac{15} {75} = \frac{1} {25}$
>
> $P(\text {neither marble is orange}) = 1 - P(\text {both marbles are orange}) = \frac{24} {25}$

However, the solution in the book is as follows:

> $P(\text {first marble is not orange}) = \frac{60} {75}$
>
> $P(\text {second marble is not orange}) = \frac{60} {75}$
>
> $P(\text {neither marble is orange}) = \frac{16} {25}$

I am unable to understand the thinking behind the author's solution.

Answer (score 1):

To say that it's not true that both are orange is **not** the same as saying neither is orange. It can happen that it's not true that both are orange and it's also not true that neither is orange. That is what happens every time one is orange and the other is not.

Answer (score 1):

There are four cases.

**Case 1**. First marble is orange, second marble is orange.
Then the statement "neither marble is orange" is **false**.
This is the case you considered.

**Case 2**. First marble is orange, second marble is **not** orange.
Then the statement "neither marble is orange" is **false**.

**Case 3**. First marble is **not** orange, second marble is orange.
Then the statement "neither marble is orange" is **false**.

**Case 4**. First marble is **not** orange, second marble is **not** orange.
Then the statement "neither marble is orange" is **true**.
This is the only case in which neither marble is orange, and it is the case the author of the book considered.

It is a legitimate method to find the probability that a statement is false, and subtract that probability from $1$ to find the probability that the statement is true. But to do that, you have to have the correct probability that the statement is false. If you only count one case where the statement is false, and ignore two other cases that each have non-zero probability, you will get the wrong answer.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, there are two approaches that arrive at the same solution:

> **Approach 1**: Calculate the probability that the first marble is orange OR the second marble is orange and subtract this from 1 (the approach taken in your solution).
>
> **Approach 2**: Calculate the probability that the first marble is NOT orange AND the second marble is NOT orange (the approach taken by the book).

$$\\$$

**Approach 1**

The probability that the first marble is orange is correct as per your solution:

> $$P(\text {first marble is orange}) = \frac {15} {75} = \frac {1} {5}$$

And since we assume that the marbles are replaced after they are drawn, the probability that the second marble is orange is also correct as per your solution:

> $$P(\text {second marble is orange}) = \frac {15} {75} = \frac {1} {5}$$

The probability that both marbles are orange will just be the product of the individual probabilities, which is also correct as per your solution:

> $$P(\text {both marbles are orange}) = \frac {1} {5} \cdot \frac {1} {5} = \frac {1} {25}$$

However, it is important to note that in this approach, we have to calculate the probability that one marble is orange and the other is not, since our final result should yield the probability that neither the first marble *nor* the second marble is orange.

Thus, the probability is as follows:

> $$P(\text {one marble is orange and the other is not}) = 2 \cdot \frac {1} {5} \cdot \frac {4} {5} = \frac {8} {25}$$

Note: We multiply this probability by $2$ since the first or the second marble could be orange, and this probability is correct as long as the other marble is not orange.

Thus, the final probability that neither marble is orange is as follows:

> $$P(\text {neither marble is orange}) = 1 - \left(\frac {1} {25} + \frac {8} {25}\right) = 1 - \frac {9} {25} = \frac {16} {25}$$

$$\\$$

**Approach 2**

The probability that neither marble is orange is simply the product of both marbles not being orange i.e. the first marble is not orange AND the first marble is not orange.

The probability that the first marble is not orange is as follows:

> $$P(\text {first marble is not orange}) = \frac {60} {75}= \frac {4} {5}$$

And since we assume that the marbles are replaced after they are drawn, the probability that the second marble is not orange is as follows:

> $$P(\text {second marble is not orange}) = \frac {60} {75}= \frac {4} {5}$$

Thus, the probability that neither marble is orange is as follows:

> $$P(\text {neither marbles are orange}) = \frac {4} {5} \cdot \frac {4} {5} = \frac {16} {25}$$

When considering the case where the marbles are not replaced (as per the original question), simply modify the probability that the second marble is orange or not.

---

I hope this helps! I'm still new to MSE, so I would really appreciate any and all feedback. Thank you!